# Social Media Managament - Feed Scheduling

Tags: 7

I am wondering if there is a module that allows you to set up a schedule and auto post to social networks?(FB and Twitter)

Comment: Once a node is published or just a schedule social media networks feeds ?

Comment: Just to schedule social media network feeds.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Feed](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) that aggregates any data you need at the rate/schedule you want.

Once you have your feed set up, you could use a service like [twitterfeed.com](http://twitterfeed.com/) to automatically post your data to the social networks of your choice.

Basically you'd just create an RSS feed and plug it into twitterfeed.